# Shifting a specific matching key-value pair from Ruby hash

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby hash:

```
@tags = { "project_status" => { "title" => "Project status" }, 
          "milestones"     => { "title" => "Milestones"},
          "lessons"        => { "title" => "Lessons"}, 
          "tasks"          => { "title" => "Tasks"} }
```

I'd like to `shift` specific key-value pairs out of this hash.
e.g. if I am interested in `"milestones"` tags, then `shift` on the hash will give me:

```
=> ["milestones", {"title"=>"Milestones"}]
```

Which is exactly what I want.

**Except** that I can't work out how to select a specific key-value pair.

I could write something to iterate through the hash until I find the matching key and then call `shift`, but I'm assuming there's a cleaner "Ruby way" to do this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delete` is probably what you're looking for. It removes corresponding key from the hash (whereas `shift` removes item from an array)

```
tags = { "project_status" => { "title" => "Project status" }, 
          "milestones"     => { "title" => "Milestones"},
          "lessons"        => { "title" => "Lessons"}, 
          "tasks"          => { "title" => "Tasks"} }

def shift hash, key
  [key, hash.delete(key)] # removes key/value pair
  # [key, hash[key]] # leaves key/value pair
end          

shift tags, 'milestones' # => ["milestones", {"title"=>"Milestones"}]
tags # => {"project_status"=>{"title"=>"Project status"}, "lessons"=>{"title"=>"Lessons"}, "tasks"=>{"title"=>"Tasks"}}
```

Comment: Thanks for this :) Is there also a way to grab the key-value pair from hash as above WITHOUT removing the key-value pair from the hash?

Comment: Sure, just use the indexer (see updated answer). Also, if you want to keep key in the hash, you shouldn't call it `shift` as it implies destructive behaviour (IMHO).